# How to make nav bar scale with resizing of browser window

Tags: html, css

My nav bar stays at its original size and does not scale when I resize the browser. I would like the bar to be centered and stay with the body of the page which is at 80% width.  The body max-width is 1900px and the min-width is 700px Do you know what I a doing wrong?

Relevant HTML:

```
<div id="hnav">
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="work.html">WORK</a></li>
<li><a href="resume.html">RESUME</a></li>
<li><a href="jordanblog.html">JORDAN BLOG</a></li>
<li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
#hnav {white-space: nowrap;
max-width: 1900px;
min-width: 700px;
text-align: center;
height: 90px;
}

nav ul {list-style-type: none;
position: fixed, center;
padding-top: 0;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding:0;
background-color: #ffffff;
}

nav li { display: inline;
}

nav {text-align: center;
list-style: none;
font-size: 24px;
}

nav a { font-family: arial, verdana;
color:#000000;
text-decoration: none; 
padding: 50px;
display: inline-block;
}

nav a:hover { text-decoration: none;
color: #bfbfbf; 
}
nav a:focus { text-decoration: none;
color: #bfbfbf;
}

nav a:active { text-decoration: none;
background-color: #000000;
color: #cccccc;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Using media queries is the best option. have a look in here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always try to use % when creating anything in css as different monitors will change the size of the website. I don't know as if the max width and height is necessary as provided you have putt that it will always be 100% for the nav bar that should be fine. Will most likely be that otherwise something else with the pixel size is wrong.

Hope this helps!